# Unwind segue hides UITabBar using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbar, unwind-segue

Good afternoon,

I'm trying to perform an Unwind segue from a ViewController to the parentViewController, but for some reason it's working but instead of showing the parentViewController wit the UITabBar (because everything is inside a TabBarController) it's showing the parentViewController without the UITabBar.

**The question is:** How can I perform an "unwind segue" and make visible the UITabBar in my parentViewController?

I perform the first segue (from parent to ViewController) using a segue "present modally" with "current context", and I use this because I need to show the UITabBar also in the ViewController.

That's my first segue (from parent to ViewController):

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject!) {
    if segue.identifier == "showPost" {
        if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {

            let navVC = segue.destinationViewController as! UINavigationController

            let childVC = navVC.viewControllers.first as! PostViewController

            childVC.id_post = posts[indexPath.row].idPost
        }
    }
}
```

And that's my unwind segue:

```
@IBAction func backToPosts(segue:UIStoryboardSegue) {}
```

Here you are and screenshot of my Storyboard:

[image]

Thanks in advance,

Regards.

Comment: can you upload your sample project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is having the same problem:

I removed the NavigationController after the TabBarController.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Try in the viewDidLoad `tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = false`

Answer (score 0):

have you tried theController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed

Comment: Not yet @DavidYangLiu, I'm going to try it tonigh and see if this works, because everything is cool and I just need that UITabBar to appear when doing the Unwind Segue. Thanks for your answer, regards